# Is Adobe Creative Cloud notoriously slow?

Tags: lightroom, macbook

I'm new to this community and am very happy to find it. I'm really not a pro and have to start off with a probably ignorant question:

I'm currently trying Lightroom for free and am now syncing 22 pictures of regular size with the cloud. It's uploading since yesterday, while my outdated Mac is visibly crumbling under the software. So, is my machine slow or Adobe's servers? Or both?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

Comment: What is 'regular size' and how fast is your network connection? Multiple hours for 22 files is not normal...

Comment: 'Is it notoriously slow?' can only have opinionated answers, or a list of 'fine for me/bad here' comments, like a facebook post. This could easily be a bufferbloat issue, entirely network-related. I'm not really sure how we can answer this question in a purely 'photographic' sense, it will quickly devolve into computer/networking troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, "Is Adobe Creative Cloud notoriously slow?" is no, it is not.  This is true of most commercial grade cloud applications.

It's important to note that upload speeds to a cloud server will be substantially slower than downloads from that same server.  This is just the way that ISPs provision their network connections and there is nothing you as a user can do about this other than to pay more for a faster network connection.

You can check your upload and download speeds for free by going to

https://www.speedtest.net/

There are, of course, other factors that can effect how well a cloud application will work for you such as the CPU performance on your computer, amount of RAM, whether you are running solid state drives or spinning hard drives and so on.  But since your question focuses on very slow uploads, the first place to check is your upload speed and performance.

It is always possible that Adobe may be dealing with a DDoS (distributed denial of service) attack at the very time you are doing these uploads.  Not terribly likely but if speedtest shows that you on a very fast line (e.g. fiber), checking with Adobe support to see if they are having outages would be the second step.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe suite is notoriously bulky and resource hungry. Probably that is what you are seeing: "is visibly crumbling under the software".

But the uploading speed is something else, so you need to test both elements separately.

1. Read and compare the system requirements vs your computer. https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-cc/system-requirements.html
2. And as Jones0610 recommended, make a speedtest.net test. In your specific case, see the uploading speed.

A speed of 1Mbps for example will take a 10Mb photo 80 seconds. For 22 photos it is only half an hour.

It is really difficult to guess what is happening on your specific case.